# Make curl multi finish download before continue?

Tags: php, curl

I have a group of urls that redirect, and I want to use curl_ multi to speed up the process to get the final url. But it seems that curl_multi haven't finished to follow redirect when I'm accessing CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL  because it return the original url.

```
function processUrls($urls){
    $handlers = [];
    $cleanUrls = [];
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    foreach ($urls as $key => $url){
        $handlers[$key] = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($handlers[$key], CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($handlers[$key], CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($handlers[$key], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($handlers[$key], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($handlers[$key], CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_setopt($handlers[$key], CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $handlers[$key]);
    }

    do {
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
        curl_multi_select($mh);
    } while ($running > 0);

    foreach($handlers as $key => $ch){
        $cleanUrls [$key] = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL) ;
    }

    curl_multi_close($mh);

    return $cleanUrls;
}
```

I think the issue is this code:

```
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
        curl_multi_select($mh);
    } while ($running > 0);
```

Comment: Where are you defining `$running` ?

Comment: Yes, that part of the code is tricky. http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php#113002  running is set up in the curl_multi_exec argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better more efficient and flexible approach using `stream_socket_client()`.  There is no delay for each url.  A slow response from one url will not affect the other url response times.  The responses will come back on a first come first serve basis. You could get the responses sequentially if necessary.

If I understand correctly you want to make some HTTP Requests where the response time can be unpredictable or too long to run consecutively and would like to run the request concurrently.

I do this when running W3C validation tools.
I do CSS validation,m HTML validation and XHTML validation. (I like my code to use as much as XHTML and only use HTML5 when necessary.  Old W3C mobile best practice habit.)

Before I transmit the `<body>` of the HTML, I start the concurrent requests using `stream_socket_client()`.

This is about as close to multi-tasking as PHP gets.  This is actual working code that I have been using for a few years.

### Initialize variables.

$url is the fully qualified URL for the page under test e.g. http://example.com/index.html

```
  $url = $_POST['url'];
  $webPageTestKey = ' [key for WebPageTest.org goes here] ';
  $timeout = 120; 
  $result = array(); 
  $sockets = array(); 
  $buffer_size = 8192;
  $id = 0;
  $urls = array();
  $path = $url;
  $url = urlencode("$url");
```

### Make the Requests with stream_socket_client()

**The request urls are stored in the $urls[] array**

```
  $urls[] = array('host' => "jigsaw.w3.org",'path' => "/css-validator/validator?uri=$url&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=no&lang=en&output=text");
  $urls[] = array('host' => "validator.w3.org",'path' => "/check?uri=$url&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&output=json");
  $urls[] = array('host' => "validator.w3.org",'path' => "/check?uri=$url&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=XHTML+Basic+1.1&group=0&output=json");
  $urls[] = array('host' => "www.webpagetest.org",'path' => "/runtest.php?f=xml&bwDown=10000&bwUp=1500&latency=40&fvonly=1&k=$webPageTestKey&url=$url");
```

sockets need the host and path.
If you cannot easily see the format of the urls dump the array with

```
var_export($urls);
```

continued:

```
  $err = '';
  foreach($urls as $path){
    $host = $path['host'];
    $path = $path['path'];
    $http = "GET $path HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: $host\r\n\r\n";
    $stream = stream_socket_client("$host:80", $errno,$errstr, 120,STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT); 
    if ($stream) {
      $sockets[] = $stream;  // supports multiple sockets
      $start[] = microtime(true);
      fwrite($stream, $http);
    }
    else { 
   $err .=  "$id Failed<br>\n";
    }
  }
```

The Request Sockets are stored in array $sockets[]

Then I transmit HTML while waiting for the requests to complete.**strong text**

### Retrieve Responses to Requests with  stream_select()

**Responses come back in the order in which they are received.  The order in which the requests were made does not matter.**

Responses are read in via an 8K buffer.  If the response is more than 8K multiple chunks are retrieved 8K at a time.

```
while (count($sockets)) {
  $read = $sockets; 
  stream_select($read, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, $timeout);
  if (count($read)) {
    foreach ($read as $r) { 
      $id = array_search($r, $sockets); 
      $data = fread($r, $buffer_size); 
      if (strlen($data) == 0) { 
        $closed[$id] = microtime(true);  // not necessary
        fclose($r); 
        unset($sockets[$id]);

        // check $response[$id] for redirect here


      } 
      else {
        $result[$id] .= $data; 
      }
    }
  }
  else { 
 //   echo 'Timeout: ' . date('h:i:s') . "\n\n\n";
    break;
  }
}
```

The HTTP Responses are stored in the $result[] array.

**You will have to add the search of the response for the redirect then make the subsequent request.**

This code gives you full control.  Nothing hidden, no unknowns.

**If you want to give up some control for ease of use.**  Make the request to your own script and use regular curl to do the requests and redirects.